# How to write rpm spec files without mentioning all the files

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, specifications

I am writing a rpm spec file to convert a tar.gz to a .rpm.

The tar contains all the files. To avoid re-writing of the spec everytime a new file is added/removed. I dont want to mention the files.

Is there a macro or somewhere I can use that will help with the above requirement?
Or should a build procedure copy the file names to the .spec file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the parent directory where you unpacked all of the files:

```
%setup
tar xvf mytarball.tar.gz -C %{buildroot}/mypkg

%files
mypkg
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`-f` option](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-files-list-directives.html#S3-RPM-INSIDE-FLIST-F-OPTION) to the `%files` directive in a spec file to say "get the list of files from this file". Using that you should be able to, quite easily, use `tar` with the `-t` flag to generate a list of filenames that need to be included in the RPM. You will probably need to do a little bit of processing on the `tar` output to get the files in the right paths but that should be fairly simple.

Additionally, if the files are all under directories that are wholly owned by the package you are building you could just list the directory itself and skip listing all the files.